# What do I lose by running Exchange 2010 in a Windows 2003 Active Directory Domain?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, active-directory, exchange-2010

I know that Exchange 2010 can be run in a Windows 2003 domain but I'd like to run it in Windows 2008.  I need to justify it though.  Will I lose anything in Exchange 2010 if I only use it in a Windows 2003 active directory?

(I will have Exchange 2010 running on Windows 2008 R2 64bit.)

Thanks.

update:  I'm not asking about domain controllers or running Exchange on a DC.  I'm asking if my Active Directory is only at the level of 2003 and I run Exchange (on my 2008 server) in that domain, what do I lose?  Or, in other words, if I put Exchange 2010 in a 2008 R2 domain, what advantage do I have in Exchange that I wouldn't have had if I had only used a Windows 2003 domain.

Comment: Are you asking about Domain Functional Levels? Or having this installed on a Domain Controller that is running 2003 or 2008? If you're talking about domain controllers, you want to have it run on it's own server and not a domain controller.

Comment: @nixphoe  updated and explained.  I do not know if there is anything I will gain by using Exchange in a 2008 AD versus a 2003 AD.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There aren't really Exchange features that are "unlocked" by having a higher domain or forest functional level. (You can have a look at the [formal support policy from Microsoft for domain and forest functional levels](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff728623.aspx)).

Answer (score 3):

Exchange doesn't care *at all* about your Active Directory version, as long as all domain controllers are at least Windows Server 2003 and the domain and forest functional levels are also Windows Server 2003; if you don't have Windows 2000 DCs around, Exchange is not going to ask for anything more.

If you have *lots* of users you might benefit from having 64-bit domain controllers (which anyway you could also create using Windows Server 2003 x64); but there really isn't anything more than that.